# UITableViewCellStyleDefault image size

Tags: iphone

I am getting some odd behavior from stock table cells, or maybe not odd, maybe I am making some assumptions.

I create the cells as follows:

```
cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
```

Then I assign an image to the default imageView property.  My image usually comes in from a user, so it might be larger than the default size.  To take care of this I:

```
 [cell.imageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
```

which I expected to scale the image for me within the control, but in reality, the images are all over the map.

So, is there a proper way to constrain the image in stock cell types?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

I don't have that problem, but am using:

cell.imageView.image = [[userPics objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] imageScaledToSize:CGSizeMake(44.0, 44.0)];
cell.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;

with a category method:

```
+ (UIImage *)imageWithImage:(UIImage *)image scaledToSize:(CGSize)newSize {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newSize);
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height)];
    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();        
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return [newImage retain];
}
- (UIImage *)imageScaledToSize:(CGSize)newSize {
    return [UIImage imageWithImage:self scaledToSize:newSize];
}
```

And yes, that retain looks suspicious.